# How to Use the table names as a list and use for loop to create tasks for all the tables in Airflow DAG?

Tags: airflow

I am trying to access the tables in mysql through for loop in my DAG. I passed the table names in list and get the values from the variables. My code working fine but the problem is in for loop am not able to get the results for all the tables only the table in the last which I mentioned in the list is recieved.

I don't know where I made a mistake can someone guide me through this..

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.transfers.mysql_to_s3 import MySQLToS3Operator
from airflow.providers.mysql.operators.mysql import MySqlOperator
from airflow.hooks.mysql_hook import MySqlHook
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.models import Variable
import json


dag = DAG(
    'Multi_Incremental_Export',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 12, 5),
    default_args={'mysql_conn_id': 'mysql_connection','provide_context' : True},
    catchup=False
)

tab1 = Variable.get('table1')

tab2 = Variable.get('table2')

tab3 = Variable.get('table3')

tables = [tab1,tab2,tab3]

start = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_task1', retries=2, dag=dag)

def max_source(**kwargs):
  ti = kwargs['ti']
  request = f"select cast(max(created_at)as char) from {tab};"
  mysql_hook = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id = 'mysql_connection', schema = 'mydata')
  connection = mysql_hook.get_conn()
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute(request)
  output = [x for x in cursor.fetchone()]
  return output[0]

def max_metatbl(**kwargs):
  ti = kwargs['ti']
  request = f"select coalesce(max(created_at),'2021-12-05 00:00:00') from {meta_tbl};"
  mysql_hook = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id = 'mysql_connection', schema = 'mydata')
  connection = mysql_hook.get_conn()
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute(request)
  output = [x for x in cursor.fetchone()]
  return output[0]

def transfer(**kwargs):
   ti=kwargs['ti']
   meta_val = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=max_meta)
   trns = MySQLToS3Operator(
   task_id ='mysql_task',
   query =f"select * from Employee where created_at >'{meta_val}';",
   s3_bucket = 'mydta',
   s3_key = f'{tab}-{val}.csv',
   mysql_conn_id = 'mysql_connection',
   aws_conn_id  = 'aws_connection',
   file_format  = 'csv',
   pd_kwargs = {'header' : False}
   )
   trns.execute(dict())

def mx_update(**kwargs):
  ti=kwargs['ti']
  meta_max = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=mx_src)
  request = f"insert into {meta_tbl} values('{meta_max}');"
  mysql_hook = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id = 'mysql_connection', schema = 'mydata')
  connection = mysql_hook.get_conn()
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute(request)
  connection.commit()

for tab in tables:

 meta_tbl = f'{tab}'+'_Metatable'

 max_meta = f'{tab}'+'_maxmeta'

 meta_updt = f'{tab}'+ '_metaupdate'

 mx_src=f'{tab}'+'_maxsrc'

 mysql_task = f'{tab}'+'_mysql_task'

 val  = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y, %H.%M")

 t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id=mx_src,
    python_callable=max_source,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
 )

 t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id=max_meta,
    python_callable=max_metatbl,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
 )

 t3 = PythonOperator(
    task_id= mysql_task,
    python_callable= transfer,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
 )

 t4 = PythonOperator(
    task_id= meta_updt,
    python_callable= mx_update,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
 )

 start >> t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4
```

Comment: it's a bad practice to have `Variable.get()` as top level code as this creates a connection to the DB every 30 seconds. You can read more about this in the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68257891/14624409

Comment: Ok, Well Instead of  `Variable.get()` I directly pass the table name in the list eventhough I got the same error.

`tables = ['Employee','Student','Staff']`

In my for loop first two table names are skipped value I am getting is only for the last table name

Comment: I am completely new to Airflow please guide me on this

Comment: Not sure if this will help but try this blog entry - https://www.cloudwalker.io/2020/12/21/airflow-dynamic-tasks/ - it does seem to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the output changes that I made was passing the table name as argument using `op_kwargs` in the python operator also included the argument the called function.

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.transfers.mysql_to_s3 import MySQLToS3Operator
from airflow.providers.mysql.operators.mysql import MySqlOperator
from airflow.hooks.mysql_hook import MySqlHook
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.models import Variable
import json


dag = DAG(
    'Multi_Incremental_Export',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 12, 5),
    default_args={'mysql_conn_id': 'mysql_connection','provide_context' : True},
    catchup=False
)

start = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_task1', retries=2, dag=dag)

def max_source(tab,**kwargs):
  ti = kwargs['ti']
  request = f"select cast(max(created_at)as char) from {tab};"
  mysql_hook = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id = 'mysql_connection', schema = 'mydata')
  connection = mysql_hook.get_conn()
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute(request)
  output = [x for x in cursor.fetchone()]
  return output[0]

def max_metatbl(tab,**kwargs):
  ti = kwargs['ti']
  table = tab
  meta_tbl = f'{tab}'+'_Metatable'
  request = f"select coalesce(max(created_at),'2021-12-05 00:00:00') from {meta_tbl};"
  mysql_hook = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id = 'mysql_connection', schema = 'mydata')
  connection = mysql_hook.get_conn()
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute(request)
  output = [x for x in cursor.fetchone()]
  return output[0]

def transfer(tab,**kwargs):
   max_meta = f'{tab}'+'_maxmeta'
   ti=kwargs['ti']
   meta_val = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=max_meta)
   val  = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y, %H.%M")
   trns = MySQLToS3Operator(
   task_id ='mysql_task',
   query =f"select * from {tab} where created_at >'{meta_val}';",
   s3_bucket = 'mydta',
   s3_key = f'{tab}-{val}.csv',
   mysql_conn_id = 'mysql_connection',
   aws_conn_id  = 'aws_connection',
   file_format  = 'csv',
   pd_kwargs = {'header' : False}
   )
   trns.execute(dict())

def mx_update(tab,**kwargs):
  ti=kwargs['ti']
  mx_src=f'{tab}'+'_maxsrc'
  meta_max = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=mx_src)
  meta_tbl = f'{tab}'+'_Metatable'
  request = f"insert into {meta_tbl} values('{meta_max}');"
  mysql_hook = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id = 'mysql_connection', schema = 'mydata')
  connection = mysql_hook.get_conn()
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute(request)
  connection.commit()

tables = ['Employee','Student','Staff','Teachers']

for tab in tables:

 max_meta = f'{tab}'+'_maxmeta'

 meta_updt = f'{tab}'+ '_metaupdate'

 mx_src=f'{tab}'+'_maxsrc'

 mysql_task = f'{tab}'+'_mysql_task'

 t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id=mx_src,
    python_callable=max_source,
    op_kwargs={"tab": tab},
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
 )

 t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id=max_meta,
    python_callable=max_metatbl,
    op_kwargs={"tab": tab },
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
 )

 t3 = PythonOperator(
    task_id= mysql_task,
    python_callable= transfer,
    op_kwargs={"tab": tab},
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
 )

 t4 = PythonOperator(
    task_id= meta_updt,
    python_callable= mx_update,
    op_kwargs={"tab": tab},
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
 )

 start >> t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4
```